# Can't use Artifactory access token to fetch encrypted password

Tags: artifactory, access-token

We want to disable UI access for our build users.
They can not use plain-text password for REST APIs for security reasons.

I am trying following to get encrypted password without allowing Build users UI access.
 - I created one build user(Non admin with UI disabled)
 - Created access token for that build user using admin account.

When I try to use Token to fetch encrypted password of build user I get following error.

```
ANYBRIDGEBUCK:~ jainish.shah$ curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" http://jainish.artifactory.com/artifactory/api/security/encryptedPassword
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "status" : 404,
    "message" : "User not found: token:automation"
  } ]
```

Is there any other way to get encrypted password without using plain-text password or via UI.

Answer (score 2):

The [Get User Encrypted Password](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-GetUserEncryptedPassword) REST API requires that the request needs to be authenticated using a clear-text password. i.e. when submitting the request to Artifactory, the password provided for authentication needs to be in clear-text.

Comment: We are not allowed to use clear-text password with REST API. Is there any other option to get Encrypted password.

Comment: @JainishShah why not using an access token or API key instead of the encrypted password?

Comment: We can use API key. But the issue remains same. Build user with UI disabled is not able to generate  API Key using access token (Created by Admin user).